# Retrieving WPF control states (checkboxes, etc.) at runtime

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a simple Windows Phone 7 project and am not using MVVM.
I have a group of check-boxes and some other controls that determine certain statuses in the UI. Let's say on checking a check-box I get an event where I have some code and would like to know the state of other check-boxes and elements in there too. Is this possible without MVVM? The root visual does not give me the main UI class (launched in main.xaml) so there seems no way to find other peer controls.

let's say I have a Listbox with checkboxes, which are databound to an xml to a Name element.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <CheckBox Name="chkBox" Checked="chkBox_Checked" Tag="{Binding name}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="16" />
       </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is used in a list

```
<ListBox x:Name="lst" SelectionMode="Single" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}" />
```

Checking an item gets me into the chkbox_Checked event. How do I determine the value of all the check-boxes in this group?

I see that lst.Items can give me the name value of the checkboxes, which is the data value they get bound to, but I am not able to cast the item to a checkBox type to inspect the isChecked value.

Comment: Please throw some sample XAML that can be useful to recreate and better understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your controls a Name in your xaml, you can reference them by this identifier in your code behind.

E.g.

```
<Button Content="Button" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" />
```

and

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    button1.Content = "Clicked";
}
```